# Value conversion HEX (u16) to RGB565 (each color as Int32)

Tags: c#, hex, rgb

I am working with a bit of an older gadget with a RGB565 color display. We have no issue displaying color to the unit but we are hoping to create some new functions for it so we want to emulate the display of our test programs. This means instead of converting from colors to a U16 HEX value... we are attempting to make colors into an identical U16 HEX value.

Unfortunately, the individual who handled the Bit Shift stuff is not with us and since I am rubbish with color and Bit Shifts... I am hoping someone here can see the following function and know exactly how to make the opposite.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Here is the code to go from RGB565 (each color as Int32) to HEX (u16):

```
    private byte[] ConvertRGB888COLORtoU16HEXasRGB565COLOR(Color color)
    {
    byte[] ReturnByte = new byte[2];
    Int32 red;
    Int32 green;
    Int32 blue;
    
    red = (Int32)Math.Floor(color.R * 31.0 / 255.0);
    green = (Int32)Math.Floor(color.G * 63.0 / 255.0);
    blue = (Int32)Math.Floor(color.B * 31.0 / 255.0);
    
    byte byte0 = (byte)(((red & 0xFF) << 3) | ((green & 0xFF) >> 3));
    byte byte1 = (byte)(((green & 0xFF) << 5) | (blue & 0xFF));

    ReturnByte[0] = byte0;
    ReturnByte[1] = byte1;    

    return ReturnByte;
    }
```

I need assistance to go the other way around as this Bit Shift stuff feels like giberish to me.

I do not know how to take the above and flip it the reservse to fill in the obvious blank in the below incomplete function:

```
    private Color ConvertU16HEXasRGB565COLORtoRGB888COLOR(byte BinaryLow, byte BinaryHigh)
    {
    ** // HELP** ================

    // BinaryLow & BinaryHigh (somehow)

    // BinaryLow & BinaryHigh and form a U16 16-Bit RGB565 value!!

    // I NEED PRIMARILY NEED HELP WITH THE OPPOSITE OF:
    // byte BinaryLow = (byte)(((Red565 & 0xFF) << 3) | ((Green565 & 0xFF) >> 3));
    // byte BinaryHigh = (byte)(((Green56 & 0xFF) << 5) | (R5 & 0xFF));

    // TO GET THE BELOW:

    // Int32 Red565 = OPPOSITE ABOVE;
    // Int32 Green565 = OPPOSITE ABOVE;
    // Int32 Blue565 = OPPOSITE ABOVE;

    ** // HELP** ================

    int Red888 = (int) floor(Red565 * 255.0 / 31.0 + 0.5);
    int Green888 = (int) floor(Green56 * 255.0 / 63.0 + 0.5);
    int Blue888 = (int) floor(Red565 * 255.0 / 31.0 + 0.5);

    Color ReturnColor = Color.FromArgb(Red888, Green888, Blue888);

    return ReturnColor;
    }
```

Comment: This cannot be the right method, or you left some pieces of it out. All color components are normalized to a byte value, but none are returned. Also, based on the normalization that is happening here, you cannot return to the exact original value

Comment: In the second snippet... do you see the:

** // HELP**

This is what I needthe answer to. It's the oppsite of the first function.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you don't understand bit shifting. That aspect is simple to explain: it's simply moving the bytes in a binary value.

For example, if we start with 0010 in `a` then we get the following results:

| Op | Result | Result as Decimal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0010 | 2 |
| a << 1 | 0100 | 4 |
| a << 2 | 1000 | 8 |
| a >> 1 | 0001 | 1 |
| a >> 2 | 0000 | 0 |

You'll note that shifting is actually just dividing or multiplying by powers of two. For example `a << 2` could be written as `a * 2^2` or `a * 4`.

We can also OR two values:

```
0110 0000 | 0000 1001 == 0110 1001
```

For each bit, we ask if either of them is 1, and if it is we write a 1 in the new byte. Otherwise we write a 0.

There is also AND. This requires that the bit in both positions be 1. For example:

```
0110 1011 | 0010 1110 == 0010 1010
```

So how can we use these operations to break down the two bytes into the constituent colours?

Let's take the regular HTML colour code #4f3f88. As RGB565, this is represented in binary like so:

```
01001001 11110001
```

So to get R, we must take the upper 5 bits of the first byte (01001). The lowest of the 5 bits must be in the 1 position, not the 8 position as it currently is. Therefore, we need to divide this by 2^3, which is to say: shift it to the right by 3 bits.

Therefore:

```
int r = b1 >> 3; // yields 00001001 (9)
```

Then to get G (6 bits), we must take the lower 3 bits of the first byte, and move them into the 6, 5, and 4 positions (they are the upper 3 bits of the G value), and the upper 3 bits of the second byte, and move them into the 3, 2, and 1 positions (they are the lower 3 bits of the G value).

To take the lower 3, we can do this:

```
int gU = b1 << 3;
```

The problem here is that we end up with 01001000, which is OK for the first 6 bits, but we're actually storing more than 6 bits in the integer, so we retain unwanted information (the 1 in position 7). Therefore, we need to first AND the R value with 00000111 so that only the information from the first 3 bits is retained. That leaves us with the following:

```
int gU = (b1 & 0b00000111) << 3;
```

Then we need the upper 3 bits of the second byte, so we need to shift it 5 to the right (as there are 8 bits to a byte):

```
int gL = (b2 >> 5);
```

Then can OR these two values together to get the G value:

```
int g = gU | gL;
```

Finally, we need the lower 5 bits of byte 2 as the b value:

```
int b = b2 & 0b00011111;
```

Putting that together we get the following:

```
int r = b1 >> 3;
int g = ((b1 & 0b111) << 3) | (b2 >> 5);
int b = b2 & 0b11111;
```

Finally we need to undo the scaling:

```
int r8bit = (int)((r / 31.0) * 255);
int g8bit = (int)((g / 63.0) * 255);
int b8bit = (int)((b / 31.0) * 255);
```

Do note that it isn't possible to get the original values out exactly as they were because converting 24-bit to RGB565 causes us to lose a little detail.

---

To provide a bit more detail on G, we essentially want to cut out 001 111 from the two bytes:

```
01001 [001   111] 10001
```

So we end up with:

```
gU: 001000
gL: 000111
```

Which we combine to get:

```
g: 001111 (15 in decimal)
```